# Arduino Uno + Sim808: Using HTTP client for GPRS GSM

Tags: arduino-uno

My problem is that I do not want to use AT commands everywhere to get/post data to my web server because it is brainstorming with all the delay and anything. I want to use library like `gsm.h` or something similar. Is there simple libraries which I can use to do the HTTP/HTTPS request (get/post) to my web server?

This code is my attempt with `gsm.h`, but it does not work. I suppose it only works with `Arduino + Telefonica GSM/GPRS shield`, not `Sim808`:

```
/*
 Web client

This sketch connects to a website through a GSM shield. Specifically,
this example downloads the URL "http://www.arduino.cc/asciilogo.txt" and
prints it to the Serial monitor.

Circuit:
* GSM shield attached to an Arduino
* SIM card with a data plan

created 8 Mar 2012
by Tom Igoe

http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/GSMExamplesWebClient

*/

// libraries
#include <GSM.h>

// PIN Number
#define PINNUMBER ""

// APN data
#define GPRS_APN       "GPRS_APN" // replace your GPRS APN
#define GPRS_LOGIN     "login"    // replace with your GPRS login
#define GPRS_PASSWORD  "password" // replace with your GPRS password

// initialize the library instance
GSMClient client;
GPRS gprs;
GSM gsmAccess;

// URL, path & port (for example: arduino.cc)
char server[] = "arduino.cc";
char path[] = "/asciilogo.txt";
int port = 80; // port 80 is the default for HTTP

void setup() {
// initialize serial communications and wait for port to open:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
    }

    Serial.println("Starting Arduino web client.");
    // connection state
    boolean notConnected = true;

    // After starting the modem with GSM.begin()
    // attach the shield to the GPRS network with the APN, login and password
    while (notConnected) {
       if ((gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER) == GSM_READY) &
       (gprs.attachGPRS(GPRS_APN, GPRS_LOGIN, GPRS_PASSWORD) == GPRS_READY)) {
          notConnected = false;
       } else {
          Serial.println("Not connected");
          delay(1000);
       }
    }

    Serial.println("connecting...");

    // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
    if (client.connect(server, port)) {
       Serial.println("connected");
       // Make a HTTP request:
       client.print("GET ");
       client.print(path);
       client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
       client.print("Host: ");
       client.println(server);
       client.println("Connection: close");
       client.println();
    } else {
      // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
      Serial.println("connection failed");
    }
}

void loop() {
     // if there are incoming bytes available
     // from the server, read them and print them:
     if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        Serial.print(c);
     }

     // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
     if (!client.available() && !client.connected()) {
        Serial.println();
        Serial.println("disconnecting.");
        client.stop();

        // do nothing forevermore:
        for (;;)
        ;
     }
 }
```

**Is there GSM/GPRS library that I can use with Sim808?**

Comment: What does Google tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start Arduino IDE, open the Library manager, search for SIM800 and there is 3 libraries available there that you can install. The advantage is that this libraries is kept up to date and when a new version is available you will get a notice to upgrade.

There is a HTTP PUT/GET library "HttpClient" that can be installed the same way as above.

**Or**

If you googlem using "sim800 library arduino" you will find several libraries like:

https://cristiansteib.github.io/Sim800l

or on github:

https://github.com/search?l=Arduino&q=sim800&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93

And as I understand it the 808 is GSM/GPRS + GPS, so the GPS features isn't normally covered by these libraries.